# Android Get Toolbar Icon Width

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how I would get the default MenuItem Width and MenuItem Padding in Android. I am unable to find a function that assist me in doing it. I have also searched online, it would be great if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: i think the width is probably set to wrap_content so there's really no "default width" since it needs to scale to the length of the items text

Comment: hmm ok.. so there is no way to get the width programmatically?